# How to add a new local branch to track the remote branch created by GitHub pages (gh-pages)?

Tags: git, github-pages

I deployed a repo to GitHub pages and it was created a new branch (gh-pages).

But on my machine, when I push changes to origin, it only goes to the master branch, and I have to, manually, add the updated content to gh-pages.

How can I add the gh-pages branch to my local machine so that I can push the changes automatically to GitHub pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a branch by using `git branch`:

```
$ git branch gh-pages
```

And then check out to it:

```
$ git checkout gh-pages
```

or use the `-b` flag to perform both operations together:

```
$ git checkout -b gh-pages
```

Once you've done that, you can perform changes and commit them, and then use the branch name when pushing:

```
$ git push origin gh-pages
```

Answer (score 0):

You must fetch the remote branch and checkout the branch.  The following assumes only one remote.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout gh-pages
```

If you are using more than one remote, then you need to be more specific on branch checkout.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/gh-pages -b gh-pages
```